# Compiler - Why is the grammar not suitable for shift-reduce

Tags: compilers

Consider this example:

```
stmt => if (expr) stmt | if (expr) stmt else stmt | other
```

Why can't we use shift-reduce on this?

This is a compiler homework and I really need to answer it.

Comment: Have you reviewed what [shift-reduce means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift-reduce_parser#Overview)?

Answer (score 1):

The grammar is ambiguous, so no deterministic parsing technique will be able to handle it. The parsing techniques called "shift-reduce" are all deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @vonbran's answer, here is why the grammar is mbiguous. Say you have a statement of the form

```
if (expr)  if (expr) stmt else stmt
```

, then the else can belong to either ifs.